# Jquery ajax inside .each How to trigger function when the whole .each is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have the following function:

```
$.each(friends, function(friend, data) {
        var group = "Chat";

$.ajax({'type':'GET', 'url':'/site/getgroup?username=' + friend,
'success':function(callback){

group = callback;
self.addFriend(friend, data.status, group);

}, //ajax success
});  //ajax

            });
```

After these codes, I have some codes to initialize the chatBar using the Data from these .each and .ajax. However, right now since Ajax is async, it becomes very buggy. How can I know that these .each are all finished with the returned ajax value without setting ajax async to false? (Means this part is completely finished).

Like is there a way I can use .promise, .complete, or XHRs to know the whole .each thing is complete? I tried out lots of stuff but they seem not to work for me.

Thank you,

Comment: I would approach that in a different way by making one Ajax request only and loop through the results in the callback. Although that solution might require some refactoring of `getgroup`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```
var xhrs = []
$.each(friends, function (friend, data) {
    var group = "Chat";
    var xhr = $.ajax({
        'type': 'GET',
        'url': '/site/getgroup?username=' + friend,
        'success': function (callback) {
            group = callback;
            self.addFriend(friend, data.status, group);    
        }, //ajax success
    }); //ajax
    xhrs.push(xhr)
});

$.when.apply($, xhrs).done(function(){
    //all are complete
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to have a status array and for each ajax request, on success/error handler to update & check the status array to see if all other ajax requests have finished. This way, you can store also the response for each ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `$.when()` as it looks like it might solve your problem. I can't say for sure what it will do to `$.each`.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/